# Toggle div depending anchor class - improving code

Tags: jquery, toggle

what i would like to get is:

clicking `<a class="example1" ...`
toggles div with the same class `<div class="example1">` regardless of its position

This code works, but can i somehow improve it?

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('a').bind('click', function() {
        var className = jQuery(this).attr('class'); 
        jQuery('div.'+className).toggle();
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some indentation would be a great improvement :).

Comment: How much simpler can it get? It's only 2 lines? Anyway, codereview.stackexchange.com is the place to ask for comments on code, SO is for solving problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Can you improve it" - I'm sure you'll get lots of interesting answers.

The code is fine.  The below are only minor tweaks for formatting and brevity:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('a').bind('click', function() {
        $('div.' + $(this).attr('class')).toggle();
    });
});
```

Although, you should probably switch to the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('a').on('click', function() {
        $('div.' + $(this).attr('class')).toggle();
    });
});
```